# Maps in List in a map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

map activity allows one map in a activity, i have a scenario and hard time implementing it, i have a list of records and for each record i show google map now this is not becoming possible in lmap activity with list having earch row a seperate map?, how can this be achived any recomendations

Comment: It would really help if you could try to be more clear - perhaps tell us what it is you're trying to implement and maybe give an example that available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I clear understood, you try to add google map on each row of standard list. It's impossible in current implementation on Android platform. As some workaround you can place on each row only snapshot from the map.

Comment: we have done this by using just one mapview and showing to any row as and when needed